# Prevent page jump from :target selector

Tags: css

So I have this modal that pops up using the CSS :target selector. However, the page jumps to the anchor when clicked. I would like to prevent the page from jumping to the :target selector. How can I do this?

```
<a href="#openModal">Info</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
```

CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 900px;
    height: 506px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

Comment: The whole *point* of an anchor is to allow you to jump to a specific part of a page - if the browser has to scroll to get to it, it will scroll. Sounds like `:target` isn't the right choice for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<a href="#/">...</a>
```

in order to change :target selector in CSS but go nowhere. The fragment #/ doesn't exists, so page won't scroll, but the :target selector will change to affect CSS change.

Answer (score 4):

Make the `.modalDialog` `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`. This will cause it to always be positioned at wherever the page is currently scrolled.

A more complete example: http://codepen.io/mblase75/pen/xbRNeV

(There's some other trickery involved in that codepen demo -- adding another target to the 'close' button on the modal which is also `fixed` keeps the page from scrolling when the modal is closed, and changing the `z-index` of your modal from `-1` to `100` (or some other suitably large integer) will keep it from blocking clicks right after you close it.)

Comment: "Other trickery" is genius. Page scroll on non-JS modal _was_ a dealbreaker for me -- but this fix is perfect. Well done!

Comment: This is should be checked as a solution

Answer (score 1):

try stopping the default action of the anchor tag

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //do your poppin' up here.
});
```

Comment: Actually if the `:target` selector is meant to show the `.modalDialog`, `preventDefault` would prevent that action too!!! That would only work if the logic of showing Modal be in the jQuery which is not right conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CSS actually, it's plain old HTML.

You have a hash id in your link, it references an element on the page. Every browser would scroll the page to the referenced element when such link is clicked. That's very standard behavior.

You can't prevent that other than by not using this technique. Well, maybe there is a way to prevent scrolling with JavaScript black magic, but you shouldn't.

Use some jQuery instead: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Basic_Show_and_Hide

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the css3 :focus selector?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Also

[CSS Menu - Keep parent hovered while focus on submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106650/css-menu-keep-parent-hovered-while-focus-on-submenu)

You can also use a `<button>` tag instead and style it however you please. That would prevent your page jumping since it is not an anchor.

Comment: It's not clear to me how one would use `:focus` instead of `:target` in this case.

Comment: While it may work to display the modal dialog, as soon as something in the dialog is interacted with, the focus will move and the dialog will disappear.